# Common variance of response variable in linear regression

Tags: regression, variance

The assumption that the variance response variable (Y given x) need to be same for all x predictors , why is it necessary ?

Comment: As with most assumptions, it's better described as an ideal condition. Much more could be said, and is said in regression texts, but if the variance isn't constant, then you should take that into account in considering what estimators to use.

Comment: @NickCox so what can be done if I try to analyse and find out that variance is not constant(by residual analysis).

Comment: Many remedies depending on precisely what is happening. It could be that plain linear regression is not the model of choice, but rather generalized linear models. Perhaps you need some estimator other than OLS. Perhaps the apparent variability in variance is not really problematic.